# HDFS: namenode.FSEditLog (JournalSet.java:mapJournalsAndReportErrors(390)) - Error: flush failed for required journal

Tags: java, hdfs, namenode

On one of our platforms, HDFS namenode is shutting down with following error message every 1 or 3 days

```
FATAL namenode.FSEditLog (JournalSet.java:mapJournalsAndReportErrors(390)) - Error: flush failed for required journal (JournalAndStream(mgr=QJM to [<ip1>:<port>,<ip2>:<port>, etc], stream=QuorumOutputStream starting at txid 29873171))
java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting 20000ms for a quorum of nodes to respond.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.AsyncLoggerSet.waitForWriteQuorum(AsyncLoggerSet.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumOutputStream.flushAndSync(QuorumOutputStream.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogOutputStream.flush(EditLogOutputStream.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogOutputStream.flush(EditLogOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet$JournalSetOutputStream$8.apply(JournalSet.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet.mapJournalsAndReportErrors(JournalSet.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet.access$100(JournalSet.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.JournalSet$JournalSetOutputStream.flush(JournalSet.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.logSync(FSEditLog.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogAsync.run(FSEditLogAsync.java:188)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Before this FATAL log we can see following kind of logs, on which we can detect a degradation of response time

```
WARN  client.QuorumJournalManager (QuorumCall.java:waitFor(185)) - Waited 18014 ms (timeout=20000 ms) for a response for sendEdits. Succeeded so far: [<ip1>:<port>,<ip2>:<port>]
```

Have you already encountered this problem, and do you have any advices to fix it ?

We have already:

- checked that our VMs are time synchronized
- detected that when the problem occurs a burst of data on the network is in progress, without detecting the root cause yet
- checked our network devices. Except a problem on a port which goes from UP state to DOWN state quickly that we are going to fix, the network seems correct

Thanks in advance